# Mock a spring bean and its internal dependencies as well

Tags: java, spring, mocking, mockito, spring-test

Hi I am new to spring test framework. I have a Spring bean which is like this -

```
BEAN A{
    @Autowired
    BEAN B;
    @Autowired
    BEAN C;
}
```

I want to mock Bean A and also its internal dependencies as well.

When I am trying to instatiate a mock instance of Bean A using Mockito, its failing with "UnsatisfiedDependencyException".

So I have to go and find each and every dependency in Bean A and mock those individually.

Is there a way I can mock a spring bean and all its internal dependencies as well in a single go?

Comment: "When I am trying to instatiate a mock instance of Bean A using Mockito" ... how do you do that?

Comment: Either is the Bean A mocked and then no internal dependencies of Band/or C  are needed. Or the Bean A is not mocked, in that case its @Autowired deps need to exist, mocked or real.

Comment: I am doing Mockito.mock(BeanA.class)

Comment: If you do Mockito.mock(BeanA.class) then there is no need to provide dependencies B and C. If you become the UnsatisfiedDependencyException then you either have somewhere not mocked definition of the bean A (i.e., one not created via Mockito.mock(BeanA.class)) or need the B and C in some other place, such as bean D.

Answer (score 0):

All what is needed to unit-test code using Bean A:

```
@Mock A a;
```

All what is needed to unit-test Bean A:

```
@Mock B  b;
@Mock C  c;

A a = new A(b, c);
```

In order to test with spring-test, test configuration could be set-up for example like this:

```
@Mock B  b;
@Mock C  c;


@Configuration static public class TestConfig {
    @Bean B b() { return b; } 
    @Bean C c() { return c; } 
    @Bean A a(B b, C c) {
        return new A(b,c);
    } 
}
```

Comment: If BeanB and BeanC has some internal dependencies as well then we will have to configure those beans also and mock them. Is there any way we can mock the whole dependency hierachy of a bean

Comment: Any bean is either mocked (using the `@Mock` annotation) or has its dependencies configured in test `@Configuration` but not both. In another words, the beans mocked by @Mock do not need their internal dependencies configured. Therefore it is not necessary to mock the whole hierarchy.

Comment: A word of terminology - a mock is an alternative implementation of a type with hard-wired behavior specific for given test case. A `@Bean` instantiated via `new` (or similarly) in some kind of test `@Configuration` and requiring its `@Autowired` dependencies in within the same `ApplicationContext` is not a mock. Not even when the `@Bean` or the `@Configuration` exists in that form only in the context of given test case.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Mockito then you can do like this:

```
@Mock
private BeanB beanB

@Mock
private BeanC beanC;

@InjectMock
private BeanA beanA;
```

You have 2 ways to make Mockito work with this:

You can annotate your test class with

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
```

The second option involve to call

```
Mockito.initMock(this)
```

in your @Before method